# Modify value of last element of grouping variable in another vector using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to modify the following dataframe such that all `x` at `ping == 3` are `NA`:

#### Data

```
d <- tibble(id = rep(c(1001, 1002), each = 6),
            day = rep(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 2),
            ping = rep(1:3, 4),
            x = rnorm(12, 5, 4),
            y = x*0.3 + rnorm(12))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
      id   day  ping     x      y
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1001     1     1  5.63  0.783
 2  1001     1     2  7.02  3.41 
 3  1001     1     3  1.72  1.29 
 4  1001     2     1 -3.00  0.154
 5  1001     2     2  3.08 -0.485
 6  1001     2     3  5.34  2.60 
 7  1002     1     1  1.42 -1.27 
 8  1002     1     2  1.31 -0.139
 9  1002     1     3  6.32  0.524
10  1002     2     1  4.43 -0.878
11  1002     2     2  6.74  3.84 
12  1002     2     3  4.79  0.782
```

#### Desired Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
      id   day  ping     x      y
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1001     1     1  5.63  0.783
 2  1001     1     2  7.02  3.41 
 3  1001     1     3  NA    1.29 
 4  1001     2     1 -3.00  0.154
 5  1001     2     2  3.08 -0.485
 6  1001     2     3  NA    2.60 
 7  1002     1     1  1.42 -1.27 
 8  1002     1     2  1.31 -0.139
 9  1002     1     3  NA    0.524
10  1002     2     1  4.43 -0.878
11  1002     2     2  6.74  3.84 
12  1002     2     3  NA    0.782
```

**How can I do this with `dplyr`?**

```
d %>%
    group_by(day) %>%
    mutate(...)
```

Comment: Try `d %>% mutate(x = ifelse(ping == 3, NA, x))`

Comment: What if I didn't know the last value of `ping` within `day`?

Comment: What do you mean by last value of grouping element? What if `ping` was `1,3,2` will the second value of `x` be `NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without grouping. I think based on your new requirements this might help:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(id, day) %>%
  arrange(ping) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() == n(), NA, x)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id, day)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
      id   day  ping      x       y
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1001     1     1  5.19   2.54  
 2  1001     1     2  0.582  1.06  
 3  1001     1     3 NA      2.63  
 4  1001     2     1  7.32   3.16  
 5  1001     2     2  2.37  -0.104 
 6  1001     2     3 NA      3.65  
 7  1002     1     1  0.249 -0.0869
 8  1002     1     2  5.61   3.62  
 9  1002     1     3 NA      1.92  
10  1002     2     1 11.5    3.79  
11  1002     2     2  5.14   1.85  
12  1002     2     3 NA      2.68
```

Comment: What if I didn't know the last value of `ping` within `day`?

Comment: In that case you have to use grouping. But I have one question in that case would you still like to get the same result? since all day `1`s and `2`s will be in the same group your `NA` values will be half of these. If so we need an additional variable to for grouping.

Comment: I would like `x` of the last `ping` within each `day` to be `NA`. So if the last ping was 4, then x for ping 3 would stay non-NA. I will update the data in the post.

Comment: I understand but you have 2 sets of day `1` and two sets of day `2`, shall we put them in the same group?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes they should be in the same group because each `id` only has only 1 set of `day` 1

Comment: I didn't notice `id` then. We can use it. Check my updates here.

Answer (score 1):

for each `id` value you can replace the `x` value with `NA` where `ping` has the `max` value.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  #group by day as well if you want to consider each day within id differently.
  #group_by(id, day) %>%
  mutate(x = replace(x, ping == max(ping), NA)) %>%
  ungroup

#     id   day  ping      x      y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1001     1     1  9.84   2.41 
# 2  1001     1     2  4.37   1.54 
# 3  1001     1     3 NA      2.37 
# 4  1001     2     1  0.305 -0.537
# 5  1001     2     2  6.96   1.92 
# 6  1001     2     3 NA      2.38 
# 7  1002     1     1  5.25   1.25 
# 8  1002     1     2 13.4    3.51 
# 9  1002     1     3 NA      2.75 
#10  1002     2     1  7.62   0.896
#11  1002     2     2  5.01   2.00 
#12  1002     2     3 NA      2.96
```